# How is this Trace equality true?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills, trace

To split the amplitude into a colour part and a kinematical part , we must start by setting up a Lagrangian.

In my notes I am told to start promoting gauge fields $A^\mu$ to be matrices:

$$(A_\mu ) ^j _i = A^a_\mu(T^a)^j _i\tag{1}$$

where $T^a$ are the generator of the **SU(N)** and *a* an adjoint index.

I am told that I must use the convention:

$$Tr[T^a T^b]=\delta^{ab}\tag{2}$$

(*instead of the standard convention which is similar but containing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ on the RHS*)

This allows the extraction of the individual $A^a_\mu$ simply through:

$$A^a _\mu= Tr [A_\mu T^a]\tag{3}$$

**I don't understand equation 3, I presume it was obtained by using equation (1) but how was this equality obtained.** This was not explained in my lecture notes and I am needing to understand it to understand the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A_\mu$ is expanded as $$A_\mu=A_\mu^bT^b$$ in terms of the generator matrices $T^b$. $A^b_\mu$ are to be thought of as coeffecients. Now, the quantity $$Tr(A_\mu T^a)=Tr(A_\mu^bT^bT^a)=A_\mu^b\delta^{ba}=A^a_\mu$$

as claimed.

The first step is essentially the first equation in your post, in explicit matrix notation instead of the index notation; your equation gives the component form of this matrix equation.